# AMchart plot time series data from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, amcharts

Hi I'm a real newbie to javascript. I'm trying to plot information to an AMchart but am having difficulty. 
The graph works when I take data from an axon query as follows.

```js
var table = amberPoint.curVal.toObj();
```

to show the following.

[image]

This next step is the one I'm having difficulty with. I extract the two object data sets into two arrays as follows.

```js
i=0;
table.forEach(function(row)
{

    var newVal;


    newVal = row.v0;
    foo[i] = [newVal];
    i++;
});

j=0;
table.forEach(function(row)
{
    var time;
    time = row.ts;
    foo2[j] = [time];
    j++;
});
```

Now I have two array with equivalent data to that in the original object.

I would like to convert these two arrays back into an object that is readable by AMchart. I do this as follows.

```js
var chartData = [];
for( k = 0; k < foo.length-10; k++ ) {
  chartData.push( {
    "x": foo2[ k ],
    "y": foo[ k ]
  } );
}
```

Unfortunately the chart does not seem to interpret the date "foo2" data correctly. I get the following result.

[image]

I'm thinking that I need to do something to the "foo2" data so that the AMchart recognises that it's a time series. Here is my chart code.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(this.view, {
    "type": "serial",

    "theme": "light",
    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled":true,
    "marginTop":0,
    "marginRight": 80,
    "dataProvider":chartData,


    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "title" : ""

    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "id":"g1",

        "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
        //"bullet": "round",
        "bulletSize": 8,
        "lineColor": "#d6ac15",
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
        "type": "line",
        "valueField": "y"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph":"g1",

        "gridAlpha":0,
        "color":"#888888",
        "scrollbarHeight":55,
        "backgroundAlpha":0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha":0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor":"#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha":0,
        "autoGridCount":true,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha":0,
        "graphLineAlpha":0.2,
        "graphLineColor":"#c2c2c2",
        "selectedGraphLineColor":"#888888",
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha":1

    },
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "hh",
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineEnabled":true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,
        "valueLineAlpha":0.5,

        "fullWidth":true

    },
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY/MM/DD JJ:NN:SS",
  // "dataDateFormat": "YYYY",
    "categoryField": "x",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "minPeriod": "hh",
        "parseDates": true,
        "minorGridAlpha": 0.1,
        "title":"DATE",
        "minorGridEnabled": true
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true


    }
});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
if(chart.zoomChart){
    chart.zoomChart();
}

function zoomChart(){
    chart.zoomToIndexes(Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.4), Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.55));
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you show how a `foo2` value looks like?

Comment: foo2 values look like the following

Comment: Aug 17, 2017 @ 5:30AM

Comment: Aug 17, 2017 @ 7:15AM

Answer (score 0):

[dataDateFormat](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) needs to match the date string format.

Please check here the options for the format: http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/

Please notice that the formats with an asterisk (*) are not supported in the `dataDateFormat`. That means you will need to change the format of the value to something like `"2017/08/17 05:30:00"`. That would match your current `dataDateFormat` that is `"YYYY/MM/DD JJ:NN:SS"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain why the date format works when using data from the original object,        var table = amberPoint.curVal.toObj();         but does not work after the object-array-object conversion?

Comment: How `amberPoint.curVal.toObj()` value looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post here so that I can post images. This is where the data in

```
amberPoint.curVal.toObj()
```

is being pulled from.

[image]

[image]

these are the two columns ts and v0

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out I had to just had to delete the dataDateFormat line.

Thanks!